# Startup Program Confusion

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, adobe-acrobat

I just noticed that in my startup programs I have Adobe Acrobat and Acrobat Manager (15) listed. Dropping it down reveals a bunch of programs, many of which are already listed as an enabled startup program to begin with. Only one of them (Adobe Reader and Acrobat Manager) looks like it's meant to be there.

[image: My startup programs]

Is there anything that I should be worried about within these startup programs (including but not limited to the thing I just mentioned)? From what I can tell, it's been like this for a while. My computer boots pretty quick, but this just seems a bit too much on the odd side, so I figure I should ask.